# antlr4 python binding for java8 missing start rule

Tags: python, java, antlr

I'm trying to use antlr on one of the grammars [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) (specifically, [java 8](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java8)):

```
$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 grammars-v4/java/java8/Java8Lexer.g4
$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 grammars-v4/java/java8/Java8Parser.g4
```

This step appears to go smooth, and when I inspect the directory:

```
$ ls -l grammars-v4/java/java8/*.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56583 Nov 30 14:32 grammars-v4/java/java8/Java8Lexer.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 798326 Nov 30 14:32 grammars-v4/java/java8/Java8Parser.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  79928 Nov 30 14:32 grammars-v4/java/java8/Java8ParserListener.py
```

everything is there. Still, when I try to use [the hello world example](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md#how-do-i-run-the-generated-lexer-andor-parser):

```
from antlr4 import *
from Java8Lexer import Java8Lexer
from Java8Parser import Java8Parser

input_stream = FileStream("/main.java")
lexer = Java8Lexer(input_stream)
stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = Java8Parser(stream)
tree = parser.startRule()
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Java8Parser' object has no attribute 'startRule'
```

Comment: You may not be having a **parser** rule named `startRule` in your parser grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser method(s), `startRule` in your case, correspond to the parser rules defined in the `.g4` grammar.

Look into the Java grammar, there is a parser rule with `EOF` in it called `compilationUnit`. Use that instead:

```py
tree = parser.compilationUnit()
```